# Why can't I access the model's property via the lambda expression parameter?

Tags: c#, razor, lambda, asp.net-core

Consider the following code behind file of a Razor page.

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    MovieContext Context { get; }

    public IndexModel(MovieContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public IList<Movie> Movies { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        Movies = await Context.Movie.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

The trimmed Razor page is given as follows

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@foreach (var item in Model.Movies)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>item.Title)
}
```

## Question

For academic purpose only, assume that I am restricted not to capture outer variables inside the lambda expression.

Why can't I use

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.Movies[modelItem.Movies.IndexOf(item)].Title)
```

instead of

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>item.Title)
```

?

Comment: Why do you want to do that ?

Comment: @Shyju: Because the lambda expression parameter is of type `IndexModel` that is passed by the framework.

Comment: But all you care about is printing the Title property of item. Rite ?Why not use the simpler version.

Comment: @Shyju: It is for academic purpose only, why it does not work. And to sharpen my knowledge.

Comment: Cause Expressions are not delegates. Expressions describe code, delegates ARE code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helpers like `DisplayFor` accept a parameter that is an expression. Not an action. It isn't executed; it is parsed.

For example, if you write

```
DisplayFor( a => a.Name );
```

...the framework does *not* just call `a.Name` to get the value. Rather, it will reflect the expression that contains `a.Name` and figure out what type and what property is being referenced. Then it looks at the property's type and attributes, e.g. [DataAnnotation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx) attributes, to figure out what is necessary to display the property.

Because of that, you are limited in the kinds of things you can provide as the argument. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displayextensions.displayfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor<code>2%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B</code>0%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B<code>0,</code>1%7D%7D%29) describes how it is used:

> - If the property is typed as a primitive type (integer, string, and so on), the method renders a string that represents the property value.
> - If the property type is Boolean, the method renders an HTML input element for a check box. For example, a Boolean property named Enabled might render markup such as the following:
>
> `<input class="check-box" disabled="disabled" ="checkbox" checked="checked" />`
>
> - If a property is annotated with a data type attribute, the attribute specifies the markup that is generated for the property. For example, if the property is marked with the EmailAddress attribute, the method generates markup that contains an HTML anchor that is configured with the mailto protocol, as in the following example:
>
> `<a href='mailto:joe@contoso.com'>joe@contoso.com</a>`
>
> - If the object contains multiple properties, for each property the method generates a string that consists of markup for the property name and markup for the property value.